# Browsers not displaying websites correctly

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. Everything seems to work pretty well except for the browsers, which do not display websites correctly. Here is a screenshot to explain what I mean:

[image: screnshot]

This happens with both Firefox and Hhrome, and something similar with all websites (either they are arranged in half the window, or they are centered but with a weirdly large amount of space on the sides). What can I do?

Comment: Perfectly normal in a widescreen. Use CTRL++ to zoom in and CTRL+- to zoom out.

Comment: That's the normal layout for google search results. Is it possible you had a very low screen resolution before you upgraded?

Comment: You could set a higher default zoom level if you prefer all websites to be rendered bigger normally. But the way it looks in your screenshot is absolutely correct and how it is meant to be for screens with resolutions like yours.

Comment: This ^^^ meaning a 4:3 "square" type monitor.

Comment: because of your monitor  its not a issue :D

Comment: You are all right, I'm dumb :D

Answer (score 0):

Type `about:config` in the address bar. and search for `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` double click and change the default value `-1` try different value. in my case 1.4 works perfectly. Hope this help.